# Hightlight line number with bat at fzf preview

Tags: linux, cut, fzf, ripgrep

I have a alias which when you pass a parameter will look like this

```
rg --trim --no-heading test_based_image $HOME/ -n | fzf --color='preview-fg:110' --preview="cut -d":" -f1 <<< {} | xargs bat "
```

The first part will return something like

```
/home/iob/path/some_file.pm:46:test_based_image
```

The preview will display the source code of some_file.pm.

My problem is i want to replace the bat command with `bat -R` to highlight the line 46.
i try to do the following

```
rg --trim --no-heading test_based_image $HOME/ -n | fzf --color='preview-fg:110' --preview="cut -d":" -f1 <<< {} | xargs bat -r $(cut -d":" -f2 <<< {}) "
```

but this fails showing this in the preview

```
[bat error]: line range contained more than one ':' character. Expected format 'N' or 'N:M'
```

Any ideas how can overcome this? i cant get where the complains come from as the bat does its thing when i run it alone.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is something like this: `rg --vimgrep . | fzf --delimiter : --preview 'bat --color=always --highlight-line {2} {1}`